# What mechanism prevents any user from accessing any other user's files via root?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, su

On a multi-user system, what protects against any user accessing any other users files via root?  As context, the question is based on my understanding as follows:

There are two commands related to root privileges, `sudo` and `su`. With `sudo`, you don't become another user (including root). `sudo` has a pre-defined list of approved commands that it executes on your behalf.  Since you are not becoming root or another user, you just authenticate yourself with your own password.

With `su`, you actually become root or another user. If you want to become user Bob, you need Bob's password. To become root, you need the root password (which would be defined on a multi-user system).

ref's: [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/111479/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-sudo-su/):

> `su` switches you to the root user account and requires the root account’s password. `sudo` runs a single command with root privileges –
>   it doesn’t switch to the root user.

and

> If you execute the su bob command, you’ll be prompted to enter Bob’s password and the shell will switch to Bob’s user account;   Similar description at [computerhope.com](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usu.htm)

[tecmint.com](http://www.tecmint.com/su-vs-sudo-and-how-to-configure-sudo-in-linux/):

> ‘sudo‘ is a root binary setuid, which executes root commands on behalf
>   of authorized users

If you become root, you have access to everything. Anyone not authorized to access another user's account would not be given the root password and would not have `sudo` definitions allowing it.

This all makes sense until you look at something like [this link](http://home.ubalt.edu/abento/linux/terminal/sudonotfedora.html), which is a tutorial for using `sudo -V` and then `sudo su -` to become root using only your own password.

If any user can become root without the root password, what mechanism protects user files from unauthorized access?

Comment: Nothing. Don't do that.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the sudo command need the root password?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150718/80216)

Comment: The important difference between su and sudo is that su usually works for everyone who knows the password of the target user, but sudo will not work at all unless the user is specifically granted admin privileges by someone that already is admin. It is possible to configure sudo to grant admin access to members of a certain user group, e.g. wheel or sudo, and Ubuntu and other root-login-disabled-by-default distros usually have such a group configured as standard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *major* difference between `sudo` and `su` is the mechanism used to authenticate.  With `su` the user must know the `root` password (which should be a closely guarded secret), while `sudo` is usually configured to ask the for the user's own password.  In order to stop all users causing mayhem, the privileges discharged by the `sudo` command can, fortunately, be configured using the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Both commands run a command as another user, quite often `root`.

`sudo su -` works in the example you gave because the user (or a group where the user is a member) is configured in the `/etc/sudoers` file.  That is, they are *allowed* to use `sudo`. Armed with this, they use the `sudo` to temporarily gain `root` privileges (which is default when no username is provided) and as `root` start another shell (`su -`).  They now have `root` access without knowing `root`'s password.

Conversely, if you don't allow the user to use `sudo` then they won't be able to `sudo su -`.

Distros generally have a group (often called `wheel`) whose members are allowed to use `sudo` to run all commands.  Removing them from this group will mean that they cannot use `sudo` at all by default.

The line in `/etc/sudoers` that does this is:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

While removing users from this group would make your system more secure, it would also result in you (or other system adminstrators) being required to carry out more administrative tasks on the system on behalf of your users.

A more sensible compromise would configure `sudo` to give you more fine grained control of who is allowed to use `sudo` and who isn't, along with which commands they are allowed to use (instead of the default of *all* commands).  For example,

```
## Allows members of the users group to mount and unmount the
## cdrom as root
%users  ALL=/sbin/mount /mnt/cdrom, /sbin/umount /mnt/cdrom
```

(only useful with the previous %wheel line commented out, or no users in the `wheel` group).

Presumably, distros don't come with this finer grained configuration as standard as it's impossible to forecast what the admin's requirements are for his/her users and system.

Bottom line is - learn the details of `sudo` and you can stop `sudo su -` while allowing other commands that don't give the user `root` shell access or access to commands that can change other users' files. You should give serious consideration to who you allow to use `sudo` and to what level.

**WARNING:** Always use the `visudo` command to edit the `sudoers` file as it checks your edits for you and tries to save you from the embarrassing situation where a misconfigured file (due to a syntax error) stops you from using `sudo` to edit any errors.  This is especially true on Debian/Ubuntu and variants where the `root` account is disabled by default.

Answer (score 7):

> There are two commands related to root privileges, `sudo` and `su`. With `sudo`, you don't become another user (including root). `sudo`has a pre-defined list of approved commands that it executes on your behalf (this addresses what I asked in the comment about how you give selected users selective privileges). Since you are not becoming root or another user, you just authenticate yourself with your own password.

This is incorrect. The most obvious difference between `su` and  `sudo` is that the latter is usually configured to ask for your own password instead of the target user's password, and that `sudo` is more flexible. Both of them's whole point is leting you become another user. `su` can run a specific command and `sudo` can start an interactive shell, they just have different default modes.

Most commonly you have a group, conventionally named [`wheel`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/W/wheel.html), that is allowed to run any command as any user. Sometimes you want to restrict a user to only run a specific command as a specific user though, and this is what's more flexible about `sudo` compared to `su`.

> With `su`, you actually become root or another user. If you want to become user Bob, you need Bob's password. To become root, you need the root password (which would be defined on a multi-user system).

You can become any user with `sudo` too, with your own password, provided that the rules in `/etc/sudoers` are set up to allow you to. `sudo` lets you restrict the command a user can run tho, yes, and prevents you from having to disclose the passwords of specific users, or even not having a password at all on specific users disallowing regular logins.

> If you become root, you have access to everything. Anyone not authorized to access another user's account would not be given the root password and would not have `sudo`definitions allowing it.

> This all makes sense until you look at something like [this link][1], which is a tutorial for using `sudo -V` and then `sudo su -` to become root using only your own password.

> If any user can become root without the root password, what mechanism protects user files from unauthorized access?
> [1]: http://home.ubalt.edu/abento/linux/terminal/sudo.html

First of all, `sudo -V` prints the version of your `sudo` binary, and `sudo -v` validates the cached credentials and are irrelevant to the later part.

Second, `sudo su` is a rather silly thing to do because there is already a `sudo` option to start an interactive shell as the specified user (`sudo -i`), and running one privilege authorization tool (`sudo`) to run another privilege authorization tool (`su`) is really silly.

Third, "any user" should definitely **NOT** be able to become root. If they can your whole system is completely unsecured. the root user is all powerful and can do anything at all, and running a command as root is only one of the uses of `sudo`, it's a general authorization tool which can let a specific user run a specific command as a specific user.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you can't.

If you allow someone (e.g. simth) in sudoer's group, he can issue a `sudo su -` then become root, then anoter user (e.g. wesson). This is an alternate way of giving root's password to simth. However he (smith) can change root passwd.

Notes also that

1) you must specify in `/etc/sudoers` a line like

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

2) smith (in the exemple above) must be in sudo group.

this is not a default setting.

You must completly trust someone (smith) to give `sudo su -` access.

Answer (score -2):

None of these answers address the question in any way.  The correct answer is file permissions prevent any user from accessing another user's file including root.  Yes, there are ways to prevent root from reading and writing to your files (or directories, which are files).

For example, a directory may contain the following entries:

drwxrwxr-x  13 root root  8192 Jan 17 15:38 bash-5.2.15
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Jan 20 08:13 bitcoin
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Dec  6 16:37 boost_1_84_0
-rwx------   1 root root 13210 Jan 19 17:44 doit_configure
-rwx------   1 root root  7491 Oct 17 11:44 doit_configure_bash

Directories start with a 'd'.  Regular files start with a '-'. Then there are the permissions to the file/directory, such as rwxrwxrwx broken into three sections:  owner, group, and other.  r=read, w=write, x=execute permission, respectively.

The 'su' and 'sudo' command utilities help with access but they are not the real answer to the original question.

Comment: "Yes, there are ways to prevent root from reading and writing to your files" -- are there?