# Difference between sudo user and root user

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, root, access-control

The `/etc/sudoers` file lists which users can do what with the `sudo` command

The root user creates and modifies the `/etc/sudoers` file.

This concept is difficult for me to understand.

If all users having sudo privilage belong to `sudoers` group, then all of them can become root by giving the `sudo su` command.

Then who is the actual root user and how does he control the powers of users in sudoers group?

Please explain it to me.

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159614/what-mechanism-prevents-any-user-from-accessing-any-other-users-files-via-root?rq=1

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Executive summary: "root" is the actual name of the administrator account. "sudo" is a command which allows ordinary users to perform administrative tasks. "Sudo" is not a user.

---

Long answer:

"root" (aka "superuser") is the name of the system administrator account. The origins of the name are a little archaic, but that doesn't matter.

Root user has user id 0 and nominally has unlimited privileges. Root can access any file, run any program, execute any system call, and modify any setting. (But see below¹).

Prior to the invention of the "sudo" command, if you wanted to perform administrative tasks, you had to login as root, either by getting a login prompt² somehow, or with the `su` command ("su" being short for substitute user.)³

That's a bit of a hassle, and also doesn't let you give users partial administrative powers. So the "sudo" command (short for "substitute user do") was invented.

The "sudo" command lets you execute commands with superuser privileges as long as your user id is in the sudoers file, giving you the necessary authorization.

So, e.g. `sudo vi /etc/hosts` would allow you to edit the hosts file as if you were running as root. You don't even need the root password, just your own login password.

And of course, `sudo su` would allow you to simply become root. The result is the same as if you had logged in as root or executed the `su` command, except that you don't need to know the root password but you do need to be in the sudoers file.

The sudoers file determines who can use the sudo command and what they can do with it.

The sudoers file is what gives you multiple administrators⁴. Effectively, your administrators are root, plus everybody listed in the sudoers file. Without the sudoers file, the only administrator is root.

In fact, in organizations where someone else administers your computer for you, it's quite common to not know the root password of your own computer — as long as you're in the sudoers file, it doesn't matter.

At one company I worked for, with a ginormous server farm, only a very, very small number of people knew the root passwords. Instead, there was a database of who was allowed to work on which servers. An automated process would add you to the sudoers files of those servers you were authorized to access, and remove you when your authorization expired.

---

¹ One more thing: modern Unix versions can now restrict even what the root user can do.

Under [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) (Security Enhanced Linux), there's effectively an access control list that determines which program can do what, and even root can't get past those restrictions.

Under Apple's [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (SIP) (aka "rootless") system, certain files and directories are locked down so that only applications on the appropriate whitelist can access them.

These systems exist to protect a system from the case where a malicious user manages to obtain root access. (Or in some cases, to prevent users from jailbreaking their embedded devices.) For obvious reasons, it's extremely difficult to bypass these restrictions, even with root access.

² The "login: " prompt is another archaic piece of Unix history, dating back to when we all used ascii terminals on serial lines, instead of window systems. You can still get a "login: " prompt by simply typing `login` in any terminal window, or by opening an ssh (or telnet or rsh) connection to your computer from elsewhere. You could log in as another user from there if you wanted. (And if your computer happens to have serial ports, you can still configure it to allow logins on them.)

³ It's also possible for individual programs to be given root access. These programs can do anything a user with root access can do, even when run by an ordinary user. These are typically limited to specific tasks. For example, the [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) program has root privileges so that it can edit the cron tables. Obviously, "sudo" has root privileges so that it can do what it does.

⁴ I'm going to cover one more point which I glossed over previously. I've been using "administrator" and "root" interchangeably, but there are other kinds of administrators. These are often called "role accounts", which is to say that these accounts don't belong to actual humans, but instead exist to perform some specific role on the system. If you take a look at the `/etc/passwd` file on your system, you'll find dozens and dozens of such accounts.

For example, if mysql was installed on your system, there would be a "mysql" user, and all of the database files, config files, and so forth would all be owned by that user. Only that user (and root, of course) would have the necessary permissions to access the files and run the mysql server. In a sense, that user would be an administrator account, but only for mysql.

If you needed to perform database administrative tasks, you would either become "mysql" with the `su mysql` command, or use `sudo` where the sudoers file would give you mysql privileges for those specific commands.

Comment: Type the `login` command and you'll be given a "login: " prompt. Type the name of the account you want to use, then the password, and now you're logged in as that person rather than yourself. This too, is antiquated, and harkens back to the time when we had terminals on serial lines instead of window systems.

Comment: If you have the necessary authorization to give the `sudo su` command, then there's no difference. Your terminology is a little off. "root" is literally the user id of the administrator of a Unix system. "sudo user" isn't really a term I've seen used before. Any user (with authorization) can give the "sudo" command, and perform actions normally only allowed to root.

Comment: Does it mean that you can have multiple administrators, and the sudoers file becomes somewhat meaningless?

Comment: "Under SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux), there's effectively an access control list that determines who can do what, and even root can't get past those restrictions." - if even root can't get pass those restrictions then who creates those restrictions in the first place?

Comment: The restrictions come from a config file that's included with the file system image when the master OS image is written to disk. The computer is effectively "born" with them. I'm afraid it's been over a year since I last worked on an SELinux system, so I've forgotten the nitty-gritty.

Comment: Oh, also: [relavant XKCD: Sandwich](https://xkcd.com/149/)

Comment: To clarify this: "Effectively, your administrators are root, plus everybody listed in the sudoers file." sudoers entries don't have to mean full root or even root-level access; I might grant Sven the ability to restart a monitoring agent that runs as moniser.

Comment: True. I glossed over the fact that sudoers can give only partial access and give privileges of users other than root. By the same token, `su` can be used to become other users than root.

Comment: I'm going to add on to the "who creates those restrictions in the first place?" question: it's also possible to have a computer without restrictions to begin with, but then someone with administrator privileges can create the SELinux config file, and then turn SELinux on. From that point forward, the config file would be unchangeable unless the administrator gave themselves access to change it. Likewise, the admin would not be able to turn SELinux back off unless they'd given themselves that access.

Comment: Also both su and sudo allow you to switch to another user account. However they differ in asking you for the target user password, or if you are part of the sudoers group, your own password. I like to think of su as "switch user" sometimes, and sudo as temporary command elevation. Should `login` still be used when you have su?

Comment: `The "sudo" command lets you execute commands with superuser privileges as long as your user id is in the sudoers file [..]`. On my machine (Solus OS 3), this is wrong. My user name is not in the sudoers file. and I can still do `sudo`.

Comment: @EdwardFalk On Ubuntu 16.04, is there a way to keep `sudo` from having access to a particular file?  I ask because I am trying to "turn off the wifi on my laptop at night" (limit my internet access while my family can still access wifi late at night).  So I would like `sudo` access to be able install new packages, but I don't want to be able to edit my `/etc/crontab` from my account with `sudo` priveleges