# How to add a new user and disable its root login?

Tags: security, sudo, users, root

A sysadmin may want to add a new user that will have no root access (nor `sudo`).

I don't sell hosting services but I can bring this field as an example; an hosting company gives its customers the ability to SSH tunnel into their own shared-hosting partition on a system (in which they won't be operate as `root` or with `sudo`, but just as a regular user, likely with many predefined technical disabilities like the absence of some common utilities).

How to create such a user a user with no sudo and not any other way to use root?

Comment: In a look. I edited the question.

Comment: Disabling root ssh only prevents people who know (or can guess) the root password from logging in as root via ssh. Normal users shouldn't know the root password, making that a non-issue. New users also don't have sudo by default, which (IMHO) turns this question into "how do I create a new user?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details of sudo config files may vary on different OS's but usually by default, users are not members of any sudoers group.

There is no per-user root account, there is only one root and you either are root or you are not root.

Sudo access can be changed through the sudoers file, but that doesn't sound like what you're trying to do.

- See [Difference between root and sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291467/235424).
- See `man 5 sudoers` for sudo configuration options.
- You can also [prevent users from using su, use pam](https://serverfault.com/a/69219/429345), but, from your question, just create a user and don't explicitly add them to the sudoers group, and make sure the root password is secure...and don't install dodgy software that runs SetUID, and you should be good.