# Drop Process Privileges

Tags: process, privileges

I have a process that gets started by a damon running as root, now I want to "downgrade" this process's privileges to those of your average user. Is this possible? If yes how?

PS: Running unix on a mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process itself has to call setuid(2).  You should also investigate running it inside chroot(8) if you aren't already.  As far as I know, there is no way for root to change the uid of another process.

If the reason you are running it as root is to bind ports, I'd suggest running it as a normal user on a higher port and using ipfw(8) on OS X to forward port 80/443/etc to the higher port:

http://support.crashplanpro.com/doku.php/recipe/forward_port_443_to_pro_server_on_mac_osx

Comment: I put setuid(uid) in my program that runs as root but I need it to run as a normal user & nothing happens i.e. it continues running as root

Comment: You probably need to catch the errors from it then(maybe you are getting an EINVAL for the uid).  Its unlikely setuid is broken on your machine you can verify by seeing if apache is running as _www.  Programmer docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setuid.2.html

Comment: you're right it gives a syntax error from the uid even though it is correct. is this the right format setuid(500)?

Comment: found the problem: I was trying to run the command through system() but I just run the command it work & solved my problem; thx for the help

Comment: No. This is not good advice: calling `setuid()` alone is absolutely not enough.

Answer (score 15):

`sudo tcpdump -Z` uses initgroups(3), setgid(2) and setuid(2) to drop the root privileges of its own process.

```
# code taken from: 
# http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcpdump/tcpdump-32/tcpdump/tcpdump.c

/* Drop root privileges and chroot if necessary */
static void
droproot(const char *username, const char *chroot_dir)
{
...
            if (initgroups(pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gid) != 0 ||
               setgid(pw->pw_gid) != 0 || setuid(pw->pw_uid) != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "tcpdump: Couldn't change to '%.32s' uid=%lu gid=%lu: %s\n",
                        username, 
                        (unsigned long)pw->pw_uid,
                        (unsigned long)pw->pw_gid,
                        pcap_strerror(errno));
                    exit(1);
            }
...
}
```

Comment: Correct. `initgroups`, `setgid`, `setuid` (last!) is precisely the right paradigm on unix, and should always be followed. In addition, a responsible "droproot" function checks that its uid and gid really have been set, even if all three primary functions returned success.

Answer (score 3):

You can run commands as other users using `su`:

```
 su USERNAME -c COMMAND
```

Will run `COMMAND` with privileges dropped to `USER`.

---

Note that, by default, `su` will use the target user's shell interpreter to run the command. By contrast, the default behaviour of `sudo` is to treat the `COMMAND` as a standalone program, that is run the current environment. Of course these default behaviours can be changed with various switches and environment variables.

Comment: Looks like `su` doesn't work if USERNAME has no shell defined (or `/bin/false`) whereas sudo does work.

Comment: @Aif If the user is not allowed to run interactive commands, then the *default* behaviour `su` will reflect that. However, one can always override that using the `-s` switch. Note that the purpose of `su` is to mimic a given user's behaviour - which is normally influenced by his/her shell. By contrast, `sudo` would (by default) ignore target user's shell setting.

Comment: No, please don't run things using a shell simply to drop privileges. That leaves far too much in the control of an attacker, reading in various config files you don't want to be touching.

Answer (score 2):

To drop privileges, you need a non-root user to drop to. Then it's just a matter of switching to that user:

```
#define UNPRIV_UID  48
#define UNPRIV_GID  48

if (getuid() == 0) { // we are root
    // setting UID/GID requires root privileges, so if you don't set
    // the GID first, you won't be able to do it at all.
    if (setgid(UNPRIV_GID)!=0) die("Failed to set nonroot GID");
    if (setuid(UNPRIV_UID)!=0) die("Failed to set nonroot UID");
}

ASSERT(getuid() != 0);
```

Note that this is done *within the program* itself, rather than in a wrapper script. Many programs require root privileges for some specific purpose (e.g. to bind to a low-numbered port), but don't need root after that. So these programs will start as root, but then drop privileges once they're no longer needed.

If you don't need root privileges at all, then just don't run it as root. E.g.:

```
# Change this:
myprog -C /my/config/file

# To this:
sudo -u someuser myprog -C /my/config/file
# Or this
su someuser -c "myprog -C /my/config/file"
```

Comment: Note that this allows the process to recover the privileges if it wishes to! The `setuid` function only sets the *effective* UID, not the real UID. You should use `setreuid` if you don't want the process to be able to get the privileges back. (And the code above doesn't deal with supplementary group privileges either. It's suitable only for launching mostly-trusted code.)

Comment: @David Schwartz code was intentionally simplified to show the mechanism used.

Comment: If you're going to simplify security-critical code, you have to make it **very** clear that this is what you're doing. And you should say things like "it's just a matter of" when it isn't.

Comment: @David Actually, `setuid()` does set real and saved userids; you may be thinking of `seteuid()`. Not all systems have `setreuid()`, so it can't be used quite everywhere. The exact semantics of `setuid()` are compliced, but if you have euid 0, you will be able to drop all traditional user-id privileges with `setuid()`. The biggest omission in this answer is that `initgroups` or `setgroups` must be called as well as `setgid` and `setuid`, and that more thorough assertions should be done at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing a different executable, i.e. you're calling `execve` or another of the `exec` familiy of function, perhaps indirectly through a function like `system` or `popen`, and the child process should run without privileges from the start, then the simplest way is to get a shell involved, and call `su`. Here's an overview of how the code might look like in Perl, showing the quoting needed for :

```
$shell_command = quotemeta($path_to_executable) . " --option";
$shell_command =~ s/'/'\\''/; # protect single quotes for the use as argument to su
$su_command = sprintf("su -c '%s' %s", $shell_command, quotemeta($user_name));
open(PIPE, "$su_command |") or die;
```

If the child process needs to start as root but drop privileges later, see [the code in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/alternative-to-su-sudo-on-barebone-system/11649#11649), which illustrates how to downgrade privileges in a process.