# How do I drop root privileges in shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script, root, centos, privileges, setuid

The "--up" option in OpenVPN is normally used for routing etc. And so it is processed before OpenVPN drops root privileges to run as nobody. However, I am invoking shell scripts that need to run as an unprivileged user.

How do I do that? I have studied [Drop Process Privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21282/drop-process-privileges), especially polynomial's and tylerl's answers, but I do not understand how to implement. I am working in Centos 6.5, and suid is blocked, both as "chmod u+s" and as "setuid()".

There is an OpenVPN plugin ("openvpn-down-root.so") which enables scripts invoked by the "--down" option to run as root. There could be an equivalent, such as "openvpn-up-user.so", but I have not found it.

**Edit0**

Per Nikola Kotur's answer, I've installed [Ian Meyer's runit-rpm](https://github.com/imeyer/runit-rpm). Although the chpst command works in terminal, in the up script it fails with "command not found". What works is "sudo chpst" plus setting the proper display and language. Please see [Why doesn't my terminal output unicode characters properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly) Given that, the up script needs these four lines:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; export LANG
GDM_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; export GDM_LANG
DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY
sudo chpst -u user -U user /home/user/unprivileged.sh &
```

**Edit1**

Per 0xC0000022L's comment, I find that "sudo -u user" works as well as "sudo chpst -u user -U user":

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; export LANG
GDM_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; export GDM_LANG
DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY
sudo -u user /home/user/unprivileged.sh &
```

I'll study man sudoers and update if/when I get sudo alone to work.

Comment: comment left by @user66229: "May I suggest that you surf to http://sourceforge.net/p/openvpn/mailman/ and subscribe to the lists that you find most appropriate."

Comment: @user66229 Thank you. But I don't believe that this is an OpenVPN-specific question. Why do you believe that it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html)'s `chpst` tool for tasks like this. For example, from the up script call your unprivileged script:

```
chpst -u nobody /path/to/script
```

Comment: Cool :) Thank you. Is https://github.com/imeyer/runit-rpm the best way to get runit into Centos 6.5? Even with Red Hat repos, I'm not finding a package.

Comment: @mirimir, yes, I use that repo when I need to build a runit package for CentOS.

Answer (score 27):

Covering only runit and sudo misses a lot.  There is actually a whole family of toolsets like runit, and a wide choice of tools for doing exactly this, the very task that they were designed for:

- Daniel J. Bernstein's daemontools has [`setuidgid`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setuidgid.html):

  ```
  setuidgid user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- util-linux (installed by default on newer Debians) has [`setpriv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setpriv.1.html):

  ```
  setpriv --reuid=user --regid=group --init-groups --inh-caps=-all /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- Adam Sampson's freedt has `setuidgid`:

  ```
  setuidgid user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- Bruce Guenter's daemontools-encore has [`setuidgid`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/setuidgid.8.html):

  ```
  setuidgid user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- Gerrit Pape's runit has [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html):

  ```
  chpst -u user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- Wayne Marshall's perp has [`runuid`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runuid.8):

  ```
  runuid user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- Laurent Bercot's s6 has [`s6-setuidgid`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-setuidgid.html):

  ```
  s6-setuidgid user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- my nosh  has [`setuidgid`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/setuidgid.html):

  ```
  setuidgid user /home/user/unprivileged.sh
  ```

They don't mix in the *different* task of *adding* privileges, and never fall into an interactive mode.

Your tacked-on problems are little more than your forgetting to have `sbin` as well as `bin` in your `PATH`, by the way.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.info/FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 8):

On Linux-based systems you can [`setpriv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setpriv.1.html) (from `util-linux`):

```
setpriv --reuid=1000 --regid=1000 --init-groups COMMAND [ARGUMENTS...]  # Like su/runuser/sudo
setpriv --reuid=1000 --regid=1000 --clear-groups COMMAND [ARGUMENTS...]  # Like daemontools setuid(8)
```

Use [`runuser`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html) if a PAM session is required (also from `util-linux)`:

```
runuser -u USER [--] COMMAND [ARGUMENTS...]
```

From the [`su`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) man page:

> **su** is mostly designed for unprivileged users, the recommended
> solution for privileged users (e.g. scripts executed by root) is to
> use non-set-user-ID command [runuser(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html) that does not require
> authentication and provide separate PAM configuration. If the PAM
> session is not required at all then the recommend solution is to use
> command [setpriv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setpriv.1.html).

Comment: `runuser` starts a PAM session. `setpriv` does not.

Comment: @ens That's correct, though I can see how my wording might be misleading. I'll rephase my answer.

Answer (score 6):

script which drops privileges and runs other script (but here I just made it to run itself):

```
#!/bin/sh

id=`id -u`
safeuser="nobody"

if [ $id = "0" ]
then
         # we're root. dangerous!
        sudo -u $safeuser "$0"      # Be sure to quote "$0"
else
    echo "I'm not root"
    id
fi
```

Example:

```
root@n3:/tmp/x# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) группы=0(root)
root@n3:/tmp/x# ./drop.sh
I'm not root
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) группы=65534(nogroup)
```

Comment: While using "sudo -u user" works for some commands, it doesn't provide enough user environment for my purposes. And while "su -l user" works fine in terminal, it does nothing in scripts. I suppose that's a security feature. So it seems that I'm left with installing runit.

Comment: @mirimir: why? `/etc/sudoers` allows to be **very** specific what environment variables can be conveyed to the program run by `sudo` and so on. `man sudoers`. Honestly, whoever uses `sudo` merely for `sudo su -` or to switch user context has no clue about what's behind this awesome program and how much you can lock down things for individual programs, users, hosts etc ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks. I took another look at sudo. And yes, "sudo -u user" plus display and language also works.

Comment: Speaking of dangerous -- you can't trust `$0`; the caller can set a script's `$0` to literally anything they want it to be. And use more quotes.

Comment: ...if your script's `$0` is `/directory/name with spaces/script` (and remember, users can create arbitrary symlinks in locations they own, even if they *don't* use `exec -a somename yourscript` to call `yourscript` with a `$0` of `somename`), then you'd get `sudo -u nobody /directory/name with spaces`, with `with` and `spaces` passed as separate arguments to your command.

Comment: @Charles, if `"$0"` is that dangerous, it hardly matters, given that we've already established that the user is uid 0 (but it is important to be aware of this in contexts where it might matter).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
sudo -Eu <user> <command>
```

You complained about environment in a previous comment, so you might also compare the differences between the outputs:

```
sudo -u <user> printenv
sudo -Eu <user> printenv
```