# Is there a POSIX (or at least a popular) utility to set the current working directory when invoking a program?

Tags: shell, freebsd, cwd

We have [env(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?env) to modify the environment of the command we want to run (for example `env MANPAGER=more man dtrace`). Is there something similar but for modifying the directory that the command is going to be started in?

Ideally, I would like it to look like this:

```
theMagicCommand /new/cwd myProgram
```

This way it could be "chained" with other env(1)-like commands, e.g.,

```
daemon -p /tmp/pid env VAR=value theMagicCommand /new/cwd myProgram
```

---

So far I can think of the following solution, which unfortunately does not have the same *interface* as env(1):

```
cd /new/cwd && myProgram
```

Also, I can just create a simple shell script like this:

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd "${1:?Missing the new working directory}" || exit 1
shift
exec "${@:?Missing the command to run}"
```

but I am looking for something that already exists (at least on macOS and FreeBSD).

`myProgram` is not necessarily a desktop application (in which case I could just use the [*Path* key in a .desktop file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)).

Comment: Why does `cd /new/cwd && env VAR=value myProgram` not meet your critera?

Comment: That's already in the question, where M. Piotrowski explained that that is not the same interface as `env`.  Look at `env`.  Compare it to `rtprio`, `idprio`, `numactl`, `jexec`, `chrt`, and indeed the commands in the toolsets mentioned in the answers.  There's a pattern, and it is chain loading.

Comment: What do you mean by “interface”? And why not use `(cd the/cwd; cmd)`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph For example, you cannot easily pass `(cd the/cwd; cmd)` to env(1) without wrapping it with sh(1).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such dedicated utility in the POSIX tool chest. But it's common to invoke `sh` to set up an environment (cwd, limits, stdout/in/err, umask...) before running a command as you do in your `sh` script.

But you don't have to write that script in a file, you can just inline it:

```
sh -c 'CDPATH= cd -P -- "$1" && shift && exec "$@"' sh /some/dir cmd args
```

(assuming the directory is not `-`). Adding `CDPATH=` (in case there's one in the environment) and `-P` for it to behave more like a straight `chdir()`.

Alternatively, you could use `perl` whose `chdir()` does a straight `chdir()` out of the box.

```
perl -e 'chdir(shift@ARGV) or die "chdir: $!"; exec @ARGV or die "exec: $!"
         ' /some/dir cmd args
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. This is indded a very handy variation of the script I included in my question. I was afraid that the utility I am looking for does not exist since its functionality is already available with a relatively short sh(1) oneliner.

Comment: If you're already running `sh`, you can also do `(cd /wherever && exec /my/command)`. The `()` implicitly opens a subshell to run the wrapped commands, and of course, `exec` gets rid of the extra shell process as quickly as `/my/command` starts running.

Comment: That was suggested in a now-deleted answer.  The questioner explained that that was not an answer to what xe asked.

Answer (score 15):

The toolsets used in the daemontools world, and elsewhere, have this and more besides; have had for many years; and are widely available.

- Wayne Marshall's perp has [`runtool`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runtool.8):

  ```
  runtool -c /new/cwd myProgram
  ```
- Laurent Bercot's execline has [`cd`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/cd.html):

  ```
  cd /new/cwd myProgram
  ```
- [my nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/) has [`chdir`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/chdir.html):

  ```
  chdir /new/cwd myProgram
  ```

All of these are chain-loading tools, designed to be used in exactly these sorts of chains.  There is a wide selection of chain-loading tools in these toolkits for other purposes.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353698/5132
- Laurent Bercot (2018-08-01). "Reference". *[execline](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/)*. skarnet.org.
- Laurent Bercot (2018-11-08). "Reference". *[s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/)*. skarnet.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[Command and tool list](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Answer (score 11):

There is such a popular program. It is called ... hold onto your chair... drumroll... `env`. The GNU version, since version 8.28, not POSIX, has the `-C` option which lets you set the directory just as you require:

```
    NAME
           env - run a program in a modified environment

    SYNOPSIS
           env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]

    DESCRIPTION
           Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.

           Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

           -i, --ignore-environment
                  start with an empty environment

           -0, --null
                  end each output line with NUL, not newline

           -u, --unset=NAME
                  remove variable from the environment

           -C, --chdir=DIR
                  change working directory to DIR

           --help display this help and exit

           --version
                  output version information and exit

           A mere - implies -i.  If no COMMAND, print the resulting environment.
```

Comment: Cool, although it is not available out-of-the-box on macOS and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

Certain programs have an option for this, like Git:

> `-C <path>`
>
> Run as if `git` was started in `<path>` instead of the current working
>   directory.

and Make:

> `-C dir`, `--directory=dir`
>
> Change to directory `dir` before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.

and Tar:

> `-C`, `--directory=DIR`
>
> Change to `DIR` before performing any operations. This option is
>   order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.

Comment: Yes. Although my question is what if `myProgram` does not provide such an option... Thank you for your contribution but I'm afraid it does not answer my question at all.