# Create startup process that requires both root and other user

Tags: users, root, privileges

I'm trying to create a service that starts a process.

I want the startup of the process to be able to do a few commands as root and then run the rest of the process as a less privileged non-human user.

For example: I know the `apache` user requires some root privileges to do some web server configuration with ports and starting various server processes but it does not run as root all the time. I can't find any code that does something similar to this and was wondering if there are any other examples I can use.

Essentially my question is, **how do I grant a non-root user temporary root privileges to run specific root only processes?**

***Or am I thinking about this the wrong way:* Do I not grant the user root privileges and instead have the root user run the root-required processes?**

Comment: A process running as `root` can always drop its privileges by changing its GID and UID to a less privileged user. see `man setgid`, `man setuid`. Please add more details about how you want to start your service.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132663/5132 .

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few options depending on exactly what you are doing as the root user.  However for automated services ("like apache"), you usually start as root and the drop to a restricted user.

Debian style configuration (including Ubuntu and Mint) would then have a file in /etc/default/*my-service-name* setting which user is switched to.  Other linux distributions have a different place to store the setting, but the technique ultimately the same.

If you are writing the service program yourself, you would use [setuid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html).  Once you've called setuid, the process cannot go back to having root privilege. 
 You will need to [lookup the user by name](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) and also [set the groups for the user](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/initgroups.3.html).

simplifying some code I wrote a long time ago:

```c
int lockToUser(const char * user) {
    # Look up the username in /etc/passwd
    struct passwd * pwd = getpwnam(user);
    if (!pwd) {
        # Failed... Could not find user, see errno
        return 0;
    }
    # setuid sets the user
    # setgid sets the main group similar to the group in /etc/passwd
    # Sets the other groups which will grant additional permissions.
    #   similar to the groups in /etc/groups
    if (initgroups(user, pwd->pw_gid) || setgid(pwd->pw_gid) || setuid(pwd->pw_uid)) {
        # Failed... Could not lock down to user, see errno
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Cave! [This does not always work in multithreaded programs on Linux](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/linux-thread-problems.html), particularly in programming languages that do not use a C run-time library, such as Go. And sometimes what one thinks is a single-threaded program is not.

Comment: @JdeBP Okay yes, having read a bit more it seems go has a specific problem because it can spawn threads before your `main()` starts.  That's not particularly common across languages.  But it's a good shout that some languages do strange things.

Comment: It's not because Go spawns threads.  It's because _Linux_ does not give a single set of credentials to all threads.  Ironically, it is _C implementations_ that do the strange things to try to hide this.

Comment: @JdeBP What I mean is your comment "sometimes what one thinks is single threaded is not".  In most languages, the simple discipline in having a single-threaded startup phase gets round the issue.  It's not so common for languages to be [dangerously] multi-threaded without the programmers explicit request to create threads.  go-lang is a notable exception where it can spawn threads before the program has even got to `main()`.  Yes the problem still exists in other languages where the developer has initiated multiple threads before calling setuid.

Comment: @JdeBP see comments from https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435#issuecomment-66054157