# Is possible to execute command as root when switched from root to user using su?

Tags: shell, freebsd, root

Same as topic.

I'm root. Then switch to user1 using

```
su - user1
```

Then execute command as root without sudo or suid/chmod. Is it possible?

One person probably did this but tells me it's a magic trick...

Comment: Would be a huge security problem if this were possible.

Comment: Add execution permissions to required executable file for target user/group

Answer (score 2):

This is not a huge security problem.  The true problem is in how people erroneously think that `su` works.

`su` *adds* privileges to a login session.  It *does not* take existing privileges away, or overlay existing processes, or create new login sessions.  One can very simply *suspend the child shell* and go back to the parent one.  Without the `-` one can even do this with the handy `suspend` command that is built-in to the C, Z, Korn, and Bourne Again shells.  With it, suspension is an only slightly more difficult exercise in the use of the `kill` utility.

The architecture of *dropping privileges* is quite different.  It involves chain-loading through programs such as `setuidgid` and *not abusing `su`* (or indeed `sudo`).  `su` (and `sudo`) is for *adding* privileges, not dropping them.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353698/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse `su` for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.