# Switch to other user instead root while using sudo

Tags: sudo, users, privileges, uid

I would like to *redirect* (switch) one execution to other user instead `root` while using `sudo`.

Example: `sudo startup.sh` will execute the `startup.sh` as `root`,
but what is needed is for it to be executed as another user, say `tomcat`.

Just for this particular execution I just want them to execute the way they are using, i.e., `sudo startup.sh`, but in the background (under the hood)
I want that to be changed to `sudo su - tomcat startup.sh` as I can't tell the users not to use `sudo -su or sudo -u`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `sudo su`. Ever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I drop root privileges in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132663/how-do-i-drop-root-privileges-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 5):

You can't easily do what you ask (i.e. make `sudo startup.sh` run as a named non-root user). What you can do, though, is one or both of the following

1. Tell users to use `sudo -u tomcat /path/to/startup.sh` instead of `sudo /path/to/startup.sh`, and disallow the latter anyway

   Add this line to your `sudoers` (remember `visudo`) such that `tomcat` here is the target user account. Change the first `ALL` to a list of users if there are only certain people allowed to run the script as the target user

   ```
    ALL    ALL=(tomcat) /path/to/startup.sh
   ```
2. Make the script perform the `sudo`, and disallow `sudo -u root` for the script. You'll need #1 (above). Ensure that `tomcat` here matches the `tomcat` in `sudoers`.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    targetUser=tomcat

    if [[ $UID -ne "$(id -u "$targetUser")" ]]
    then
        exec sudo -u "$targetUser" "$0" "$@"
        exit 1
    fi

    # ...script continues but as the $targetUser...
   ```

   This allows people to run `/path/to/startup.sh` (or even just `startup.sh` if it's in the `$PATH`) and not worry about the `sudo` part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sudo` with a `-u` switch.

Example:

```
sudo -u tomcat whoami
```

Comment: Well just for this particular execution i just want them to execute the way they are using i.e. sudo startup.sh but in the background i want that to be changed to sudo su - tomcat startup.sh as i can't inform the users not to use sudo -su or sudo -u

Comment: I'd just add 'tomcat   ALL=/usr/bin/startup.sh' (change /usr/bin/ to where ever your script is located) to /etc/sudoers.